# Apple Pay Loyalty NFC API

Tags: ios, nfc, applepay

I've seen that Walgreens and other merchants have integrated with Apple Pay's loyalty scheme. Is there a loyalty API that we can access or do they a partnership with Apple to allow this via NFC? I've read it's using the Wallet API but I can't see where the loyalty aspect is in the API.

http://techcrunch.com/2015/11/05/walgreens-becomes-first-retailer-to-integrate-its-loyalty-program-with-apple-pay/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access the Loyalty API. The Walgreens code and the Apple code will interact through a interface/common file. So basically you can only view the interface/common file where the Apple code and the Walgreens code communicate at maximum but not the Loyalty API.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So if a shop had a loyalty scheme, would they need to work with Apple to integrate it into the Apple Pay wallet? Or is there documentation on this common file?

Comment: The shop would basically use the NFC Readers that would have compliance with the Walgreen and Apple PAy Wallet. The reader would emit an Application Identifier(AID) that would be captured by your phone NFC and in the NFC Controller(Chip) there would be something called the routing table where this AID will be matched with the Apple Pay Wallet AID and thereby the Wallgreen event is finally routed to the Apple Pay Wallet. The shop keeper has no role in this but just to buy a reader and advertise that his/her reader would support so and so companies or whatever..

Comment: Great, that makes sense. Thanks!